# jquery deferred exeption with tablesorter in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, tablesorter

EDIT:
Anyone can help with this please? I've literally copy/pasted from the tablesorter website. I have it working perfect outside of Laravel but once I try put it in Laravel i get the themes error below. Is laravel not seeing something and I have to point towards it? if so, what? how? It's really starting to grind my gears.

I'm currently trying to wrap my head around Laravel and a now trying to add tablesorter.

I have the .css and .js files in the public/css or js folders and am calling them with the below links.

```
<!-- Tablesorter -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-latest.min.js') }}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/theme.bootstrap.css') }}">
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.tablesorter.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js') }}"></script>
```

But I keep getting the below error.

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'themes' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'themes' of undefined
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://192.168.0.13:8080/orders:27:19)
at l (http://192.168.0.13:8080/js/jquery-latest.min.js:2:29375)
at c (http://192.168.0.13:8080/js/jquery-latest.min.js:2:29677) undefined
```

Am I missing something? Thanks.

Edit:

The themes should be dealt with in the standard tablesorter javascript right?

```
     $(function() {

        // NOTE: $.tablesorter.theme.bootstrap is ALREADY INCLUDED in the jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js
        // file; it is included here to show how you can modify the default classes
        $.tablesorter.themes.bootstrap = {
            // these classes are added to the table. To see other table classes available,
            // look here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables
            table        : 'table table-bordered table-striped',
            caption      : 'caption',
            // header class names
            header       : 'bootstrap-header', // give the header a gradient background (theme.bootstrap_2.css)
            sortNone     : '',
            sortAsc      : '',
            sortDesc     : '',
            active       : '', // applied when column is sorted
            hover        : '', // custom css required - a defined bootstrap style may not override other classes
            // icon class names
            icons        : '', // add "bootstrap-icon-white" to make them white; this icon class is added to the <i> in the header
            iconSortNone : 'bootstrap-icon-unsorted', // class name added to icon when column is not sorted
            iconSortAsc  : 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up', // class name added to icon when column has ascending sort
            iconSortDesc : 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down', // class name added to icon when column has descending sort
            filterRow    : '', // filter row class; use widgetOptions.filter_cssFilter for the input/select element
            footerRow    : '',
            footerCells  : '',
            even         : '', // even row zebra striping
            odd          : ''  // odd row zebra striping
        };

        // call the tablesorter plugin and apply the uitheme widget
        $("table").tablesorter({
            // this will apply the bootstrap theme if "uitheme" widget is included
            // the widgetOptions.uitheme is no longer required to be set
            theme : "bootstrap",

            widthFixed: true,

            headerTemplate : '{content} {icon}', // new in v2.7. Needed to add the bootstrap icon!

            // widget code contained in the jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js file
            // use the zebra stripe widget if you plan on hiding any rows (filter widget)
            widgets : [ "uitheme", "filter", "columns", "zebra" ],

            widgetOptions : {
                // using the default zebra striping class name, so it actually isn't included in the theme variable above
                // this is ONLY needed for bootstrap theming if you are using the filter widget, because rows are hidden
                zebra : ["even", "odd"],

                // class names added to columns when sorted
                columns: [ "primary", "secondary", "tertiary" ],

                // reset filters button
                filter_reset : ".reset",

                // extra css class name (string or array) added to the filter element (input or select)
                filter_cssFilter: "form-control",

                // set the uitheme widget to use the bootstrap theme class names
                // this is no longer required, if theme is set
                // ,uitheme : "bootstrap"

            }
        })
        .tablesorterPager({

            // target the pager markup - see the HTML block below
            container: $(".ts-pager"),

            // target the pager page select dropdown - choose a page
            cssGoto  : ".pagenum",

            // remove rows from the table to speed up the sort of large tables.
            // setting this to false, only hides the non-visible rows; needed if you plan to add/remove rows with the pager enabled.
            removeRows: false,

            // output string - default is '{page}/{totalPages}';
            // possible variables: {page}, {totalPages}, {filteredPages}, {startRow}, {endRow}, {filteredRows} and {totalRows}
            output: '{startRow} - {endRow} / {filteredRows} ({totalRows})'

        });

    });
```

Comment: Problem is elsewhere, in your code there is no `themes` property.

Comment: should the themes property not be dealt with in the standard tablesorter javascript? (edited question to show)

Comment: Everything *looks* okay in the code that was shared... if you're using Bootstrap v4, you won't need the "uitheme" widget. Also make sure that only one version of jQuery is being loaded.

Comment: ok, so bootstrap.js seems to be loading jQuery. Deleting the extra jquery i added gives this error: jQuery is not defined, and replacing the jQuery.js file that bootstrap.js loads with the one i added gives the same error.